# Concatenate list in python (Discord Bot)

Tags: python, discord, bots

I wanted to program a bot in python. I'm currently following this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPTfmiYiuok&t=2454s).

As I tried to implement the options variable (40:55) everything was fine but as I wanted to test the bot in Discord (currently at min 48:19) the bot doesn't add the new encouragement.

This is my code:

```
options = starter_encouragements
  if "encouragements" in db.keys():
    options = options + db['encouragements']
```

And this is the starter_encouragements list:

```
starter_encouragements = [
  "Cheer up!",
  "Hang in there!",
  "You are a great person / bot!"
]
```

The error message: [image]

Comment: `options = options + list(db['encouragements'])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TypeError is providing a useful piece of information. Your code is attempting to concatenate an ObservedList to a list. They are two different data structures. The ObservedList is a data structure defined in the replit package. In [their tutorial](https://github.com/replit/replit-py/blob/fc47b96202667ca8a04827285a19e94912bdca29/docs/db_tutorial.rst) they explain:

> Under the hood, this feature works by replacing the primitive list and
> dict classes with special replacements that listen for mutation,
> namely replit.database.database.ObservedList and
> replit.database.ObservedDict.

So the question becomes, "How do I get the list contained in the ObservedList so I can add the values to another List?" And that is pretty straight-forward. To get the list contained in the ObservedList, call the `value` attribute.

```
db[“encouragements”].value
```

Change your code to:

```
options = starter_encouragements
  if "encouragements" in db.keys():
    options = options + db['encouragements'].value
```

If for some reason that does not work, try python's `extend()` method instead of the `+` operator. You need to use [Mutable Sequence Type operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types).

```
options = starter_encouragements
  if "encouragements" in db.keys():
    options = options.extend(db['encouragements'])
```

Comment: Can I also change the message? Because now the bot says: 
ObservedList(value=["Don't worry! Everything will be alright!"])                          Can I change this to ["Don't worry! Everything will be alright!"]?

Comment: You should be able to change the message by updating the variable. For example, 

`db['encouragements'].value += "My new encouragement"`

Comment: This doesn't work. I even tried it this way: `options = options + "My new encouragement" + db['encouragements'].value`

Comment: You will want to ask another question with specific code samples instead of following up in the comment section. It may be worth checking out the comments or discord channels of [people working through the same tutorial](https://replit.com/@BeauCarnes/Encourage-Bot) too.